How to show IVP has unique solution
Given
$$
y' = \frac{ty+y}{ty+t}, \ 2\leq t\leq 4, \ y(2) = 4
$$
How do we show the solution and that it is unique. I have been able to get closer to a solution but I have not been able to isolate the $y$. Also how can I show this has a unique solution, all the theorems I know of cannot be applied to this which has made me stuck for quite a while now.

You could define $y = e^z$ and show that the equation in $z$ has a unique solution, which looks simpler. Also try to use separation of variables.

What theorems? Why they cannot be applied to this ODE? Also, there is nothing wrong with a solution in implicit form, if that is what you obtained.

Please include the progress that you have made towards a solution.

For the existence and uniqueness of a solution there is the Picard–Lindelöf theorem, also known as the existence and uniqueness theorem.

I tried separation of variables and got y + ln(y) = t + ln(t) + 2+ln(2), also since the derivative is not continuous I can't use the existence and uniqueness theorem which is why I am having trouble finding out how to show it is unique.

It only has to be continuous on a neighborhood of (2,4).

Ok got it, thank you so much. Is there a result about this which I can look more into?

Suppose $y_1,y_2$ are two solutions satisfying
$$
y_i' = \frac{(t+1)y_i}{t(y_i+1)}, \ 2\leq t\leq 4, \ y_i(2) = 4, i=1,2.
$$
Since $y_i(2)>0$, it is easy to see $y_i(t)>0$ for $t\in[2,4]$. Define $u=y_1-y_2$. Then $u(2)=0$ and
$$
u' = \frac{(t+1)y_1}{t(y_1+1)}-\frac{(t+1)y_2}{t(y_2+1)}=\frac{t+1}{t}\frac{-u}{(y_1+1)(y_2+1)}.
$$
So
$$\begin{eqnarray}
|u(t)|&=&|u(t)-u(2)|=\bigg|\int_2^tu'(s)ds\bigg|\\
&\le&\int_2^t|u'(s)|ds\le \int_2^t\frac{s+1}{s}\bigg|\frac{u(s)}{(y_1(s)+1)(y_2(s)+1)}\bigg|ds\\
&\le&3\int_2^t|u(s)|ds. 
\end{eqnarray}$$
By the Gronwall Inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality, one has
$$ |u(t)|\le |u(2)|e^{3(t-2)}=0, t\in[2,4]. $$
So $u(t)=0$ for all $t\in[2,4]$.
